# How can I redirect only after transaction is finalized?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, paypal

In the sample code I have for checking out with paypal, there is a redirect request to a route `purchase/complete`. I'd like to ensure that this route is requested only after the post request to `/paypal/purchase/complete` has been completed so that I can get the `orderID` created on the server side and pass it as a get parameter to the `purchase/complete` route so that it would resemble something like `purchase/complete?orderId=XXXX`. XXXX here would be the received `data.orderID`

Client side:

```
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({

      // Set up the transaction
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        var payableAmount = $("#finalAmountTotalOrders").attr("amountData");
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
              value: payableAmount
            }
          }]
        });
      },

      // Finalize the transaction
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
          //will redirect user to custom page change values as desired
          window.location.replace("/purchase/complete");
          // Call your server to save the transaction
          return fetch('/paypal/purchase/complete', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              orderID: data.orderID,
              details: details

            })

          });

        });
      }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

**Edit:**

The reason I'd like to do this is because although I am able to create an order and store it in my database once the `/paypal/purchase/complete` post request is made, I'm not sure when I would do something like email the customer and merchant with the ID of the order (database row) I just created. Trying to do it in the post request throws an error so if I could just get the ID on the `/purchase/complete` route, I can query the database and get the order details and email it. Any other approach would be useful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out you can just chain another `.then` block right after the first `actions.order.capture().then` block

```js
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        //will redirect user to custom page change values as desired
        // Call your server to save the transaction
        return fetch('/paypal/purchase/complete', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            orderID: data.orderID,
            details:details

        })

        }).then((response) => {
          window.location.replace("/purchase/complete?paypalOrderId="+data.orderID);
        });

    });
  }
```